# Secruing a API for Javascript Requests

Tags: javascript, api, security, oauth

I am about to create a API for my web service. Now it's time to think about security.
There will be multiple clients accessing my API, however their all created by me, so no third party clients.
For now I planned a mobile App (Phonegap / JS), a web app (Also JS) and a Chrome App (also JS).

Sadly I don't have the possibility to use HTTPS for my API requests. Thats why I thought about oAuth 1 for security.

My question now: How safe is it to use oAuth in combination with JS, because the Secrets will be stored client side.

Is oAuth a good decision or could anybody recommend a alternative?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does your web-site require user logins?  If so, a common practice is to require a user login cookie before accepting the Ajax request and, if someone is trying to abuse your Ajax API, you can at least remove that user account so they can't continue to abuse it (until they manually create a new account and start again, but at least you have some control and trackability of the user of your API).

Comment: Many other APIs require an APIKey.  For your own use in the web page, you can embed the APIKey in the page.  While someone can certainly fish it out of the web page and use it for their own use, if you find that's being abused, you simply put a different APIKey into your web page and block the APIKey that was being used before.  You can even rotate your APIKey automatically every day so that nobody can code a long running app that uses your API without regularly refreshing the APIKey.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've got bad news for you.

oAuth is not safe at all. You need to use SSL. The only way to be secure is to have a third party, that is trusted by the web browser vendor, provide a certificate signed to prove that you are who you claim to be. Without that, anybody on the same LAN as the user can easily hack into your system.

Also note that oAuth 2.0 actually requires an SSL connection anyway.

Finally some more bad news, you cannot store any secrets client side. Client side is controlled by anyone who uses your app, and they can access all secrets you store there. It is impossible to change this, SSL won't help either.

The takeaway is:

- you need to use SSL, there's no alternative.
- you must not store any secrets client side. All secrets must be server side.

Comment: It seems you haven't described a solution for keeping random agents out their API yet so it's a little premature to say SSL is required.  If the data itself doesn't need to be sure, then I would think that the need for SSL needs to be evaluated in the context of a particular solution for keeping random agents out of their API.

Comment: @jfriend00 I haven't described a solution for keeping random agents out because there is no such solution. It's as impossible goal. You have to store a secret client side to achieve it, and you cannot store secrets client side. All users will be able to access the secret and all users will be able to share the secret with the world.

Comment: Yeh, I know so I don't understand what you're saying SSL is required.  SSL is only required if you need to secure the actual data in transport or protect a secret.  If no login secret is being used (since you can't from a browser client) and the data doesn't have to be protected, why would SSL be required for an Ajax request?

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. Yes I need my users to login. Data would not necessarily be secured. But how is for example google (i.e. Drive) is doing this? As far that i know theyre using oAuth, ans there is a mobile App and a Browser and a Chrome App. So it has to work somehow?!

Comment: @jfriend00 SSL doesn't just do encryption, it also proves that the server you are talking to is the server you expect to be talking to, and that nobody is performing a man in the middle attack. This is the part of SSL that costs money and it's the most important part.

Comment: @phspe Google drive uses oAuth or something similar, and SSL, and they do not store any secrets on the device. Anybody can make a google drive client, it's public.

Comment: Yeah, I know the other things SSL does.  Suppose I have an API that lets people search a recipe database (query only).  Why would I have to use SSL for that?

Comment: @jfriend00 under HTTP 2.0 you will have to use SSL, but until that is adopted it depends whether or not you want there to be any security.